# constructing a convex and absorbing set in where its balanced hull is not convex

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, convex-analysis

I am trying to draw/construct a convex and absorbing set where its balanced hull is not convex

Definitions: "A is a subset in a vector space E"

1. A is convex if for every x and y in A, and t in[0,1], then t*x+(1-t)*y in A.
2. A is balanced set if for every x in A and t in [-1,1], then t*x in A.
3. A is absorbing set if for each x in E, there exists a>0 such that x in a*A.
4. balanced hull of A is the intersection of all balanced sets that contain A.

If also there is recommended basic textbook that talks about these terminologies and how to draw them, it would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is convex and $0\in A$, it is easy to check that $A\cup-A$ is balanced and that $-A$ is a subset of the balanced hull of $A$.  Hence $A\cup-A$  is its own balanced hull, and hence is the balanced hull of $A$.

Let $A$ be the interior of a non-circular ellipse in the plane, one of whose foci is at the origin.  Its balanced hull is $A\cup -A$, which has a pair of dimples.

Or: $A=\{(x,y):x>-1, y>-1\}$.  Then again, the balanced hull is $A\cup -A$, which is not convex.  For instance, the point $(2,-2)$ is not in $A\cup-A$ but is in its convex hull.

Comment: Thank you for the example, I see A is convex and absorbing, but I don't see why A∪−A is not convex? in other words, if x in A and y in -A, then tx+(1-t)y in A∪−A, right?

Comment: I have added an example.  Another example.  In the conventional Venn diagram for $A\cap B$, imagine $B=-A$.  Both $A$ and $B$ are absorbing convex disks, but their union is not convex.

Comment: right! Can i ask how did you get balanced hull is A∪−A? I know balanced hull is the intersection of all convex sets that containing A.

Comment: In your problem statement you wrote "balanced hull of A is the intersection of all balanced sets that contain A", without any convexity restriction.  I have edited my answer covering this point, with your original definition.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, let $A=[-1,2]^2$. The balanced hull is
$A \cup (-A)$.

[image]